# Upload files without refreshing the page by using ajax post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a page file-upload.jsp with the code snippet below:

```html
 <form action="" id="frmupload" name="frmupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="file" id="upload_file" name="upload_file" multiple="" />
     <input type="submit" value="Update" />
 </form>
```

I have 2 questions:

1. The moment I select some files, i.e the `onchange` event of the `input` type `file`, the file(s) should get uploaded.

   I have a Java page that receives multipart request parameter and uploads the file to the said location. My problem is the form submission `onchange`, so that the Java file can proceed with further operations.

   I googled and went through lot of articles. Some say it's not possible to upload files directly via Ajax, some say submit the form to an iframe via Ajax/jQuery.

   I tried a lot of code from internet, such as this:

   ```js
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $('upload_file').change(function(){
           var data = new FormData();
           data.append('file', $(this[0].files[0]));
           $.ajax({
               url: 'photo.jsp',
               type: 'post',
               contentType: attr('enctype', "multipart/form-data"),
               data: data,
               success: function(data){
                   alert(data);
               }
           })
       });
   });
   ```

   but could not get the expected results.
2. I also need a progress bar for the upload operation.

Answer (score 4):

Look at this example using an IFrame, is in PHP but changing the action should do the trick

[Ajax Style File Uploading Using Hidden IFrame](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/ajax-style-file-uploading-using-hidden-iframe/)

Answer (score 2):

Since you're already using jQuery, I would definitely go for the [jQuery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/), which allows you to do form uploads via AJAX, even if the form contains a `file` input.

There is an [example](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload) on its website available that shows how to display a progress bar.

Comment: The example which you showed is using ajax but what I want is file upload like you see on facebook or mail boxes i.e the moment  you select some files the upload should start and you preview the files on the page and neednot press the submit button.After everything is ok then i want the submit button to be pressed for actually upload to happen

Comment: the jquery code which i have provided is just one of the many ways I tried .Any other ways for the same is welcome

Answer (score 0):

Look at this example it is exact as you want

http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/ajaxcontroltoolkitsamplesite/asyncfileupload/asyncfileupload.aspx